# Header image in WordPress site doesn't display on iPhone

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site http://legacyproject.sbcc.edu using the “twenty seventeen” theme with a custom header .jgp image, file size: 456 KB, dimensions: 2000 x 1200 (as recommended for that theme). It displays fine on a desktop computer but the header image does not appear on an apple iPhone. (I don’t have an iPad to check it on, so I don’t know how it appears there.) I see from a previous question/answer that image size can be an issue, but my image appears to fall within the acceptable range. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**: It was suggested I scroll down to the bottom of my mobile device and click the "View full site" link. It worked. I now see the site as it previewed in the mobile-friendly version in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to disable **Jetpack plugin** or [Mobile Theme](https://jetpack.com/support/mobile-theme/) functional of Jetpack to show visitor exactly what you see on desktop.

[image: Jetpack Mobile Theme]